# how to create 3-D array using single loop and single iteration variable

Tags: algorithm

```
$result = Array();
for ($x = 0; $x < 6; $x++){
    for ($y = 0; $y < 6; $y++){
       for ($z = 0; $z < 6; $z++){
           $result[$x][$y][$z] = $x * $y * $z;
        }
    }
}
```

In above code three for nested loops has been used and three different iteration variables are used. Is there any way we can create array using single iteration variable and single for loop. Please Suggest.

Comment: what language you are using, please specify only one

Comment: I'm guessing you are interested in Algo rather than actual loop

Comment: Why do all the variables prefixed with `$`? I know it doesn't make any difference, I'm just curious.

Comment: kind of too broad question

Answer (score 2):

You can compute your array index from a global index:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 6 * 6 * 6; $i++) {
    $x = Math.floor($i / (6 * 6));
    $y = Math.floor(($i / 6) % 6);
    $z = $i % 6;
    $result[$x][$y][$z] = $x * $y * $z;
}
```

Comment: @NinaScholz: Fixed. Answered from an other language tag :-/

Answer (score 0):

actual implementations may vary  from language to language.. The most universal way is to calculate indexes of array based of global index.

```
$x = $i / (Y_SIZE * Z_SIZE);
$y = ($i / Z_SIZE) % Y_SIZE;
$z = $i % Z_SIZE;
```

That might be actually slower than using three loops ( and  asking  compiler to calculate memory, because division and  modulus are the slowest of operations.  with three loops you have  supposedly three increments, two multiplications, three  additions and three comparison operations. With one loop, you have increment, 2 divisions/multiplication and 3 modulus  (which are equal to  a division,  comparison and  rounding and addition together) and one comparison plus, two multiplications(from accessing the 3d array by indices) and three additions. That doesn't look good. If this is javascript or java, it's even worse, because arrays work different from  native languages.

Let's assume we speak about C++ or C:

```
int array[Z][Y][X];
```

Equivalent of

```
array[a][b][c]
```

is

```
*(*(*(array + c) + b) + a)
```

or

```
*( (int*)((char*)array) + a*Y*Z + b*Y * a )
```

latter  can be replaced by single index, of course

Answer (score 0):

You could use an approach with [`Number#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) and a radix of `6`. Then take the single characters as value.

```js
var result = [],
    i,
    temp;

for (i = 0; i < 6 * 6 * 6; i++){
    temp = ('00' + i.toString(6)).slice(-3);
    result[temp[0]] = result[temp[0]] || [];
    result[temp[0]][temp[1]] = result[temp[0]][temp[1]] || [];
    result[temp[0]][temp[1]][temp[2]] = temp[0] * temp[1] * temp[2];
}
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommended Object instead of Array.

```js
$result = {};
for ($x = 0; $x < 6; $x++){
    for ($y = 0; $y < 6; $y++){
       for ($z = 0; $z < 6; $z++){
           $result[[$x, $y, $z]] = $x * $y * $z;
        }
    }
}

document.querySelector('textarea').value = JSON.stringify($result, null, '  ');
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

```
{
  "0,0,0": 0,
  "0,0,1": 0,
  "0,0,2": 0,
  "0,0,3": 0,
  ....
  "5,5,4": 100,
  "5,5,5": 125
}
```

Otherwise:

```
$result = [];
for ($x = 0; $x < 6; $x++){
    $result[$x] = [];
    for ($y = 0; $y < 6; $y++){
       $result[$x][$y] = [];
       for ($z = 0; $z < 6; $z++){
           $result[$x][$y][$z] = $x * $y * $z;
       }
    }
}
```